# How to parse a string into a hash table in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, parsing, hashtable

I am getting data as a string from a remote device. I need to parse the data. The data usually come like this:

```
MO                SCGR  SC         RSITE           ALARM_SITUATION
RXOTG-59            59  0          EK0322          ABIS PATH FAULT
RXOCF-59                           EK0322          LOCAL MODE
RXOTRX-59-0         4              EK0322          LOCAL MODE
RXOTRX-59-1                        EK0322          LOCAL MODE
RXOTRX-59-4             0          EK0322          LOCAL MODE
RXOTRX-59-5         1   3          EK0322          LOCAL MODE
RXOTRX-59-8                        EK0322          LOCAL MODE
RXOTRX-59-9                        EK0322          LOCAL MODE
```

I will love to have the data as an array of arrays or any other programmatically sensible structure.

I am splitting the data into an array using:

```
str.split("\r\n")
```

and then removing the extra space on each element in the array with:

```
tsgs.map! {|tsg| tsg.gsub(/\s+/, " ").split(" ") }
```

but this has limitation in that the empty cells are not considered. I expect the array to contain five elements, but it instead contains less than five.

Case 1: In this case, I get the expected result:

```
RXOTG-59            59  0          EK0322          ABIS PATH FAULT
```

converts to

```
["RXOTG-59", "59", "0", "EK0322", "ABIS PATH FAULT"]
```

Case 2: In this case, I get an unexpected result:

```
RXOTRX-59-9                        EK0322          LOCAL MODE
```

converts to

```
["RXOTRX-59-9", "EK0322", "LOCAL MODE"]
```

```rb
   def getCommandResult(tgdatas)
        tgdatas_arr = tgdatas.split("\r\n")
        tsgs = tgdatas_arr[5..tgdatas_arr.index("END")-2]
        tsgs.map! {|tsg| tsg.gsub(/\s+/, " ").split(" ")[0] }
        return tsgs
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your string<sup>1</sup>, modified slightly:

```
data = <<END
MO                SCGR  SC         RSITE           ALARM_SITUATION
RXOTG-59            59  0          EK0322          ABIS PATH FAULT
RXOCF-59                           EK0322          LOCAL MODE
RXOTRX-59-0         4              EK0322          LOCAL MODE
RXOTRX-59-1                        EK0322          LOCAL MODE
RXOTRX-59-4             0
RXOTRX-59-5         1   3          EK0322          LOCAL MODE
RXOTRX-59-8                        EK0322          LOCAL MODE
RXOTRX-59-9                        EK0322          LOCAL MODE
END
```

This string looks very much like CSV data structure, so we might be tempted to convert it to a CSV string, thereby allowing us to bring to bear the methods provided by the [CSV](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) class.

**Convert string to CSV string**

*Code*

```
def convert_to_csv(data)
  cols = data[/.+?\n/].gsub(/ \S/).map { |s| Regexp.last_match.begin(0) }
  data.each_line.map do |s|
    cols.each { |i| s[i] = ',' if s.size > i+1 }
    s.gsub(/ *, */, ',')
  end.join
end
```

*Convert string*

Now convert the string `data` to a CSV string.

```
csv_data = convert_to_csv(data)

puts csv_data
MO,SCGR,SC,RSITE,ALARM_SITUATION
RXOTG-59,59,0,EK0322,ABIS PATH FAULT
RXOCF-59,,,EK0322,LOCAL MODE
RXOTRX-59-0,4,,EK0322,LOCAL MODE
RXOTRX-59-1,,,EK0322,LOCAL MODE
RXOTRX-59-4,,0
RXOTRX-59-5,1,3,EK0322,LOCAL MODE
RXOTRX-59-8,,,EK0322,LOCAL MODE
RXOTRX-59-9,,,EK0322,LOCAL MODE
```

*Explanation*

The steps are as follows.

```
s = data[/.+?\n/]
  #=> "MO                SCGR  SC         RSITE           ALARM_SITUATION\n" 
e0 = s.gsub(/ \S/)
  #=> #<Enumerator: "MO ... ALARM_SITUATION\n":gsub(/ \S/)>
cols = e0.map { Regexp.last_match.begin(0) - 1 }
  #=> [17, 23, 34, 50] 
e1 = data.each_line
  #=> #<Enumerator: "MO ... LOCAL MODE\n":each_line> 
a = e1.map do |s|
  cols.each { |i| s[i] = ',' if s.size > i+1 }
  s.gsub(/ *, */,',')
end
  #=> ["MO,SCGR,SC,RSITE,ALARM_SITUATION\n",
  #    "RXOTG-59,59,0,EK0322,ABIS PATH FAULT\n",
  #    ...
  #    "RXOTRX-59-9,,,EK0322,LOCAL MODE\n"] 
a.join
  #=> < return value above >
```

Let's have a closer look at the calculation of `a`. First, the block variable `s` is assigned to the first element generated by the enumerator `e1`:

```
s = e1.next
  #=> "MO                SCGR  SC         RSITE           ALARM_SITUATION\n"
```

The block calculation is then performed:

```
cols.each { |i| s[i] = ',' }
s #=> "MO               ,SCGR ,SC        ,RSITE          ,ALARM_SITUATION\n"
s.gsub(/ *, */,',')
  #=> "MO,SCGR,SC,RSITE,ALARM_SITUATION\n"
```

The regular expression used with `gsub` reads, "match zero or more spaces followed by a comma, followed by zero or more spaces".

When the short line is passed to the block the following calculation is performed.

```
s = "RXOTRX-59-4             0"
s.size
  #=> 25
cols
  #=> [17, 23, 34, 50] 
cols.each { |i| s[i] = ',' if s.size > i+1 }
s #=> "RXOTRX-59-4      ,     ,0" 
s.gsub(/ *, */,',')
  #=> "RXOTRX-59-4,,0"
```

The remaining elements of `e1` are processed similarly.

**Convert the CSV string to a hash**

We may now make use of CSV methods. For example, suppose we wish to create an array of hashes whose keys are the header elements, downcased and converted to symbols and values of `"SCGR"` and `"SC"` are to be converted to integers. To do that we make use of the class method [CSV::new](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-new), specifying appropriate values for method options.

*Construct the hash*

```
require 'csv'

CSV.new(csv_data, headers: true, header_converters: :symbol,
  converters: :all).to_a.map(&:to_h)
  #=> [{:mo=>"RXOTG-59",    :scgr=>59,  :sc=>0,   :rsite=>"EK0322",
  #     :alarm_situation=>"ABIS PATH FAULT"},
  #    {:mo=>"RXOCF-59",    :scgr=>nil, :sc=>nil, :rsite=>"EK0322",
  #     :alarm_situation=>"LOCAL MODE"},
  #    {:mo=>"RXOTRX-59-0", :scgr=>4,   :sc=>nil, :rsite=>"EK0322",
  #     :alarm_situation=>"LOCAL MODE"},
  #    {:mo=>"RXOTRX-59-1", :scgr=>nil, :sc=>nil, :rsite=>"EK0322",
  #     :alarm_situation=>"LOCAL MODE"},
  #    {:mo=>"RXOTRX-59-4", :scgr=>nil, :sc=>0,   :rsite=>nil,
  #     :alarm_situation=>nil},
  #    {:mo=>"RXOTRX-59-5", :scgr=>1,   :sc=>3,   :rsite=>nil"EK0322",
  #     :alarm_situation=>"LOCAL MODE"},
  #    {:mo=>"RXOTRX-59-8", :scgr=>nil, :sc=>nil, :rsite=>"EK0322",
  #     :alarm_situation=>"LOCAL MODE"},
  #    {:mo=>"RXOTRX-59-9", :scgr=>nil, :sc=>nil, :rsite=>"EK0322",
  #     :alarm_situation=>"LOCAL MODE"}]
```

*Explanation*

The steps are as follows.

```
csv = CSV.new(csv_data, headers: true, header_converters: :symbol,
  converters: :all)
  #=> <#CSV io_type:StringIO encoding:UTF-8 lineno:0 col_sep:",
  #         " row_sep:"\n" quote_char:"\"" headers:true> 
a = csv.to_a
  #=> [#<CSV::Row mo:"RXOTG-59" scgr:59 sc:0 rsite:"EK0322" alarm_situation:"ABIS PATH FAULT">,
  #    #<CSV::Row mo:"RXOCF-59" scgr:nil sc:nil rsite:"EK0322" alarm_situation:"LOCAL MODE">,
  #    ...
  #    #<CSV::Row mo:"RXOTRX-59-9" scgr:nil sc:nil rsite:"EK0322" alarm_situation:"LOCAL MODE">] 
a.map(&:to_h)
  #=> < hash shown above >
```

<sup>1 To run the code you will need to un-indent this heredoc (or change the first line to `data = <<-END.lines.map(&:lstrip).join`).</sup>

Comment: Note that @iGian had the same idea of converting the string to a CSV string in his earlier answer.

Comment: I noticed that convert_to_csv method has no return statement, is there a reason for that?

Comment: One could write `return data.each_line.map do |s| ... end.join`, but the keyword `return` is redundant because `data.each_line.map do |s| ... end.join` is the last expression evaluated in the method. Its return value is therefore the return value for the method.

Comment: Hi, I noticed one more thing, when the ALARM_SITUATION field is empty, I mean without even empty space it does not run check this link, https://rextester.com/YAB84581

Comment: Emmanuel, thanks for the heads-up. I fixed that and changed the example slightly to illustrate the issue.

Comment: There was a proposed edit that had been rejected by moderators prior to me having seen it. I didn't notice who posted it and it now seems to be gone. I would like to thank whoever posted it, as I think it related to a problem that Emmanuel noted in a comment above (which I've subsequently fixed). I do think it's generally preferable, however, to inform the author of a problem in a comment, possibly suggesting a fix, but let the author perform the needed edit.

Answer (score 4):

[String.unpack](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-unpack) with directive "A" is nice for fixed width strings.

```
str = "RXOTRX-59-9                        EK0322          LOCAL MODE"
p str.unpack("A20A4A11A16A15" ) # => ["RXOTRX-59-9", "", "", "EK0322", "LOCAL MODE"]
```

Comment: That's good to know, very useful. I noticed that if the length of the string is less than `20+4+11+16+15`, `unpack` effectively pads the string with spaces to make it the indicated length before executing the directive (a convenience).

Answer (score 3):

Try if this can be viable for you, given the `data_string`:

```
data_string = "MO                SCGR  SC         RSITE           ALARM_SITUATION\nRXOTG-59            59  0          EK0322          ABIS PATH FAULT\nRXOCF-59                           EK0322          LOCAL MODE\nRXOTRX-59-0         4              EK0322          LOCAL MODE\nRXOTRX-59-1                        EK0322          LOCAL MODE\nRXOTRX-59-4             0          EK0322          LOCAL MODE\nRXOTRX-59-5         1   3          EK0322          LOCAL MODE\nRXOTRX-59-8                        EK0322          LOCAL MODE\nRXOTRX-59-9                        EK0322          LOCAL MODE"
```

Set the starting point of each line, since it seems to be aligned with the header.

```
data = data_string.split("\n")
starts = [0, 18, 24, 35, 51, (data.map(&:size)).max ]
```

Then map each line considering the starting points, stripping trailing spaces:

```
data = data.map { |line| starts.each_cons(2).map { |a,b| line[a..b-1].strip } }
```

So you'll end up with this array:

```
# [["MO", "SCGR", "SC", "RSITE", "ALARM_SITUATION"]
#  ["RXOTG-59", "59", "0", "EK0322", "ABIS PATH FAULT"]
#  ["RXOCF-59", "", "", "EK0322", "LOCAL MODE"]
#  ["RXOTRX-59-0", "4", "", "EK0322", "LOCAL MODE"]
#  ["RXOTRX-59-1", "", "", "EK0322", "LOCAL MODE"]
#  ["RXOTRX-59-4", "", "0", "EK0322", "LOCAL MODE"]
#  ["RXOTRX-59-5", "1", "3", "EK0322", "LOCAL MODE"]
#  ["RXOTRX-59-8", "", "", "EK0322", "LOCAL MODE"]
#  ["RXOTRX-59-9", "", "", "EK0322", "LOCAL MODE"]]
```

You can then convert it to a hash or use the csv library to manipulate your data.

---

Here is a way to generate an array of hashes:

```
headers = data[0]
body = data[1..]

body.map { |line| headers.map(&:to_sym).zip(line).to_h }
#=> [{:MO=>"RXOTG-59", :SCGR=>"59", :SC=>"0", :RSITE=>"EK0322", :ALARM_SITUATION=>"ABIS PATH FAULT"}, {:MO=>"RXOCF-59", :SCGR=>"", :SC=>"", :RSITE=>"EK0322", :ALARM_SITUATION=>"LOCAL MODE"},  ...
```

Comment: It would be better if you can get the indices in `starts` automatically using the header information. See that each column name does not include a space? Also, the complicated code to get the last index is unnecessary. You can have `0` there.

Comment: @sawa, thank you for pointing that `0` works anyway as last starting point. I did not added automation for finding the starting points because being not comfortable with regexp I came up with an ugly: `data[0].each_char.each_cons(2).with_index.with_object([]) { |((a, b), i), res| res << i + 1 if (a == ' ' && b != ' ')}`. So, I decided to pass over.